# Flask redirect after job done to previous url

Tags: flask

in flask

template

```
<a href="{{url_for('delete',file_path=file_path)}}">
<img src="/static/icons/backspace-fill.svg" alt="" width="12" height="12" title="Delete">
</a>
```

app.py

```
@app.route("/delete/<path:file_path>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete(file_path):
    os.remove(os.path.join(root_path, file_path))
    return redirect(request.url)
```

I'd like to return back my previous url(not delete...) after being directed to "/delete/..."
How can this be achived with minimal of implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the url you want to redirect to in your delete.

```
<a href="{{url_for('delete',file_path=file_path, redirect_url='...your_redirect_url_here...')}}">
    <img src="/static/icons/backspace-fill.svg" alt="" width="12" height="12" title="Delete">
</a>
```

Then you can grab it in your route and redirect accordingly

```
@app.route("/delete/<path:file_path>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete(file_path):
    os.remove(os.path.join(root_path, file_path))
    return redirect(request.values['redirect_url'])
```

This is commonly done with login forms where after a successful login the user is redirected to the original url they tried to access. You can google "Flask Login next parameter" for more info.

Comment: Super thanks ! Did not find this in the flask site